# How import a HTML file Template Email into an Activiti Task Email?

Tags: html, xml, alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

I've got this task in a BPMN Actitivi.
I would like to put a template.html file into   tag.

Is there any way?

Thanks

```html
<serviceTask id="P3_EnviarEmail" name="Enviar Email Inicial" activiti:type="mail">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:field name="from">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[info@xxx.om]]></activiti:string>
        </activiti:field>
        <activiti:field name="to">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[xxxxx@gmail.com]]></activiti:string>
        </activiti:field>
        <activiti:field name="subject">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[Comienzo del Evolutivo]]></activiti:string>
        </activiti:field>
        <activiti:field name="html">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[ HERE HTML CODE ]
```

Comment: Why not do it the normal Alfresco way, and store the Email Template in the Alfresco data dictionary?

Comment: I'm using Activiti without Alfresco in standalone mode

Comment: In my case I usually implement emails in event listeners or system activities. This way allows for a finer control for the email formatting and sending. For instance, this approach allows me to add attachments or even create a full report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution using Java.

I load files templates in Java, then I pass these to BPM like variables.

This is the code

**JAVA**

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public String getResources(String nombreFichero) throws IOException {
   String content = IOUtils.toString(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + nombreFichero + ".html").getInputStream(),"UTF-8");
    return content;
}

String templateHeader = "";
    String templateFooter = "";

    try {
        templateHeader = getResources("templateHeader");        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        templateFooter = getResources("templateFooter");            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**CALL TASK IN JAVA**

```
    Map<String, Object> taskVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    taskVariables.put("templateHeader", templateHeader);
    taskVariables.put("templateFooter", templateFooter);
```

**BPM**

```
        <serviceTask id="P3_EnviarEmail" name="Enviar Email Inicial"
        activiti:type="mail">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:field name="from">
                <activiti:string><![CDATA[xxxxxxx@xxx.com]]></activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
            <activiti:field name="to">
                <activiti:string><![CDATA[xxxxxxx@xxx.com]]></activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
            <activiti:field name="subject" expression="Comienzo del Evolutivo ${evolutivo.nombre}" />
            <activiti:field name="html">
                <activiti:expression>
                            <![CDATA[
                                ${templateHeader}       
                                ${templateFooter}
                             ]]>            
                </activiti:expression>
            </activiti:field>
        </extensionElements>
    </serviceTask>
```